# Demo's frontend differs from starter frontend

Tags: frontend, solidus

On the Solidus website, there is a link to the demo. The frontend in the demo looks different from when I install Solidus on my local server. This also applies to the administrative part. Why is that, and how can I make my frontend look the same as in the demo?

Just install Solidus with starter-frontend